# What exactly does a pthread mutex lock out?

Tags: pthreads, mutex, parallel-processing

I'm assuming this has been asked on here, but I can't find this particular question.  Does it just lock the part of the code in between the lock and unlock, or does it lock global variables?  Like for this code

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&mtx);
bitmap[index] = 1;
pthread_mutex_unlock(&mtx);
```

the mutex just locks that line of code?  Is there a way to lock specific variables without just locking the part of code that uses them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it locks the actual *mutex variable.*

*Any* piece of code that attempts to lock that mutex while it's locked will block until it's unlocked.

If that is the only piece of code that locks the mutex then, yes, you can say it just protects that line. But that's not necessarily the case.

A mutex is used to serialise access to a resource. Whether that resource is considered a line of code or (more likely in this case) the `bitmap` array is down to where the mutex is locked and unlocked.

Chances are you have a few different areas where the `bitmap` array is read or modified and you should probably ensure they're *all* protected by the mutex.

Comment: is it possible to lock only one element in a vector/array/data set?  since i don't need to worry about them accessing different elements at the same time.  or do i?  is it even possible though?

Comment: Yes, it's possible, if you have one mutex per element. It's also _incredibly_ inefficient :-) I've seen situations where you have (for example) one mutex per thousand array elements in a set of ten thousand but a one-to-one ratio would be ... unusual.

Comment: ah so then you'd have an array of mutexs that correspond to segments of the data array, and then do a check if they are the same range?

Comment: @FrederickCraine: yes, though you could simplify the "same range" checking. Example, a 10,000-element array in ten groups: `int element[10000]; mutext_t mutex[10]; lock (mutex[i/1000]); element[i]++; unlock (mutex[i/1000]);`.

Answer (score 3):

No there is no way to just lock a variable.

Mutex is just an abstraction. So whenever you want some variable should not be affected when you are working on it, declare a mutex for that variable and lock it as long as you want.

There is no direct relation between the mutex and the variable you want to lock. Its up to the programmer. Most commonly it is used in multi-threaded environment.

Whenever a variable (a resource. In programming, resources are manipulated in variables) is shared across parallel running processes (according to kernel, threads of a same process are a group of processes sharing same address space and some resources), if a programmer want to make the variable to be accessed exactly only one process at a particular time, he has to write the block of code accessing the variable in all the processes (or threads) between a mutex lock pair (pthread_mutex_lock and pthread_mutex_unlock). So whenever the variable is accessed in any process (or thread), mutex will be locked. So if another process want's to access the variable, it has to wait until the mutex unlock. So the programmers' final goal is achieved.